# Angular, apply a style on a HTMLElement

Tags: css, angular, typescript, styles, htmlelements

I have an issue with Typescript, i'm trying to apply a style on a HTMLElement, here is the code :

```
 styleChoice(element:HTMLElement){
    console.log(element);
    element.style.background="rgba(228, 48, 48, 0.2)";
    element.style.borderRadius="40px";
  
  }
  test(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('test'));
    this.styleChoice(document.getElementById('test'));
   
  }
```

I don't understand why is not working.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: The style isn't applied on the id

Comment: And the element is correctly logged in both functions?

Comment: Yes, the console is displaying the exact same element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Renderer2 for this to work. It will be a good option. Don't use the document directly in the app, check [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/angular-manipulate-properly-the-dom-with-renderer-16a756508cba) for more details.

```
export class DemoComponent {
  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
  ){

  }

styleChoice(element:HTMLElement){
    console.log(element);
    //element.style.background="rgba(228, 48, 48, 0.2)";
    renderer.setStyle(el, 'background', 'red');
    renderer.setStyle(el, 'borderRadius', '40px');
   // element.style.borderRadius="40px";
  
  }
  test(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('test'));
    this.styleChoice(document.getElementById('test'));
   
  }
}
```

You can check here for [renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Angular way, an Angular way is to use a variable and [`[ngStyle]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

e.g.

```
//in .ts
style={
   "background":"rgba(228, 48, 48, 0.2)",
   "borderRadius":"40px"
}
//in .html
<some-element [ngStyle]="style">...</some-element>

//or directly
 <some-element [ngStyle]="{'background':'rgba(228, 48, 48, 0.2)',
                                        'borderRadius':'40px'}">
     ...
 </some-element>
```

You can change the style according a variable, e.g.

```
variable=true;
<some-element [ngStyle]="variable?style:null">...</some-element>
```

If only want to change one property you can use `[style.property]`

```
//in .ts
backgroundColor="rgba(228, 48, 48, 0.2)"
//in .html
<some-element [style.background]="backgroundColor">...</some-element>
```